# WebStorm not recognising browser.get or browser.getTitle()

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, webstorm

Wondering if someone could help with a problem I'm having with WebStorm and trying to run Protractor tests using the Jasmine framework.

I believe I have imported all the relevant JavaScript libraries and Node packages but when using the IDE the `browser` part of the code is always underlined and WebStorm says "unresolved variable". For example `browser.getTitle()`.

Could anyone explain why I'm having this issue? I have tried removing the libraries and re adding them and adding some additional ones which I thought might make a difference.

[image: Libraries]

[image: Libraries - 2]

[image: Code]

Comment: Did you have installed protractor in your project via npm install?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I just started with Protactor and WebStorm, did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @S.Huston I removed all npm packages and started again